# Problem installing ca-certificates-java package within Debian bookworm docker image

Tags: docker, debian

I have a Dockerfile using the latest Debian image which is bookworm. Besides other things I try to install tex-live in the container which obviously requires java jdk to be installed which in turn depends on ca-certificates-java.

Unfortunately the installation of openjdk-17-jre-headless crashed because there is an error while setting up "ca-certificates-java".
This is what my pipeline tells me:

```
#5 76.76 Setting up ca-certificates-java (20230103) ...
#5 77.12 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.InternalError: Error loading java.security file
#5 77.13    at java.base/java.security.Security.initialize(Security.java:106)
#5 77.13    at java.base/java.security.Security$1.run(Security.java:84)
#5 77.13    at java.base/java.security.Security$1.run(Security.java:82)
#5 77.13    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318)
#5 77.13    at java.base/java.security.Security.<clinit>(Security.java:82)
#5 77.13    at java.base/sun.security.jca.ProviderList.<init>(ProviderList.java:178)
#5 77.13    at java.base/sun.security.jca.ProviderList$2.run(ProviderList.java:96)
#5 77.13    at java.base/sun.security.jca.ProviderList$2.run(ProviderList.java:94)
#5 77.13    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318)
#5 77.13    at java.base/sun.security.jca.ProviderList.fromSecurityProperties(ProviderList.java:93)
#5 77.13    at java.base/sun.security.jca.Providers.<clinit>(Providers.java:55)
#5 77.13    at java.base/sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:156)
#5 77.13    at java.base/java.security.cert.CertificateFactory.getInstance(CertificateFactory.java:193)
#5 77.13    at org.debian.security.KeyStoreHandler.<init>(KeyStoreHandler.java:50)
#5 77.13    at org.debian.security.UpdateCertificates.<init>(UpdateCertificates.java:65)
#5 77.14    at org.debian.security.UpdateCertificates.main(UpdateCertificates.java:51)
#5 77.14 dpkg: error processing package ca-certificates-java (--configure):
#5 77.14  installed ca-certificates-java package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
#5 77.15 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of openjdk-17-jre-headless:amd64:
#5 77.15  openjdk-17-jre-headless:amd64 depends on ca-certificates-java (>= 20190405~); however:
#5 77.15   Package ca-certificates-java is not configured yet.
#5 77.15 
#5 77.15 dpkg: error processing package openjdk-17-jre-headless:amd64 (--configure):
#5 77.15  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
#5 77.15 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of openjdk-17-jdk-headless:amd64:
#5 77.15  openjdk-17-jdk-headless:amd64 depends on openjdk-17-jre-headless (= 17.0.8+7-1~deb12u1); however:
#5 77.15   Package openjdk-17-jre-headless:amd64 is not configured yet.
#5 77.15 
#5 77.15 dpkg: error processing package openjdk-17-jdk-headless:amd64 (--configure):
#5 77.15  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
#5 77.16 Processing triggers for sgml-base (1.31) ...
#5 77.21 Setting up libfontconfig1:amd64 (2.14.1-4) ...
#5 77.30 Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.36-9+deb12u1) ...
#5 77.46 Errors were encountered while processing:
#5 77.46  ca-certificates-java
#5 77.46  openjdk-17-jre-headless:amd64
#5 77.46  openjdk-17-jdk-headless:amd64
#5 77.52 E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
#5 ERROR: process "/bin/sh -c apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y software-properties-common &&     apt-add-repository 'deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security bookworm/updates main' && apt update -y &&     apt-get install -y openjdk-17-jdk-headless ca-certificates-java" did not complete successfully: exit code: 100
```

Is there some way to fix this problem?

I have experimented with answers to similar previously asked questions about installation of openjdk-8-jre-headless. But nothing helped so far.

Comment: You'll probably want to be adding your dockerfile here.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced with the same issue running on `python:3.[7-11]-slim` images which are built on top of `debian:slim`.

I got it fixed installing mine dependency (jing, which is using jre) in the beginning of Dockerfile, so basically it consisted of:

```
ARG TAG="3.8-slim"
FROM python:${TAG}

RUN set -x \
    && apt-get update \
    \
    #: force installing jing due to different issues regarding to java runtime environment \
    #: setup issues (see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76872534/12171959)
    && apt-get install jing -y \
    #: other setup instructions ...
```

I assume this might help. And yet more, if you add `ca-certificates apt-transport-https gnupg2` along with jing, it fails to build an image.

Comment: many, many thanks. You solved my problem. My dockerfile is working again!